# Entering additional rows in dataframe as mid points between values of adjacent existing rows

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, missing-data

Say you have the following time series dataset in r:

```
n <- 3
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Day = rep("Mon", n),
           Time = 1:n,
           Temper = round(rnorm(n, 4, 2), 0))
print(df)

  Day Time Temper
  Mon    1      3
  Mon    2      4
  Mon    3      2
```

Now say you wish to add midpoints between adjacent existing values as extra rows in the data frame. For example, say you wish to add the exact midpoint between every pair of adjacent values, to produce the following new dataframe:

```
  Day Time Temper
  Mon    1      3
  Mon  1.5    3.5
  Mon    2      4
  Mon  2.5      3
  Mon    3      2
```

What would be some efficient R code that could accomplish this on much larger datasets?

It would be great if this code could also populate the dataframe with values which are not just the exact midpoints, for example the 'one-third' datapoint:

```
  Day Time Temper
  Mon    1      3
  Mon 1.33   3.33
  Mon    2      4
  Mon 2.33   3.33
  Mon    3      2
```

Comment: Can you share how you got 3.33 in row 2 (excluding header) and column 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 2)) %>%
  mutate_at(c("Time", "Temper"), function(x) {
    replace(x, seq(2, n(), 2),
            (x + (1 / 3) * (lead(x) - lag(x)))[seq(2, n(), 2)])
  }) %>%
  mutate_at(c("Time", "Temper"), round, 2) %>%
  slice(-n())
#>   Day Time Temper
#> 1 Mon 1.00   3.00
#> 2 Mon 1.33   3.33
#> 3 Mon 2.00   4.00
#> 4 Mon 2.33   3.33
#> 5 Mon 3.00   2.00
```

Comment: thanks @Ashirward how would I adjust this to get the results in the second table? Using 0.333 instead of 0.5 seems to cause some problems. Now just seen your comment above.. It would be 33% of the way from 4 to 2. So 3.33. Or 4+0.33*(2-4).

Comment: @Will T-E, just give it a try now. I fixed the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using `dplyr` and `purrr`. We first `rbind` rows of `NA` and we then fill those NAs, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  map_dfr(rbind, NA) %>%
  fill(Day) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(2, 3)), funs(replace(., is.na(.), (1/2) * (lag(.) + lead(.))[is.na(.)] ))) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
>     Day  Time Temper
>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1     1   1      3  
> 2     1   1.5    3.5
> 3     1   2      4  
> 4     1   2.5    3  
> 5     1   3      2
> ```

Comment: thanks @Sotos but this doesn't seem to be 'averaging' the last column. Row 4 column 3 needs to be 3.33 not 4.33.

Comment: Oh you want the average? I thought you just wanted to add half, third, etc...let me edit

Answer (score 1):

You may want to benchmark (cf library microbenchmark) those 3 solutions, depending on the numbers of factors and numeric variables you have.

#### Using base R

```r
n <- 3
set.seed(1)
dframe <- data.frame(Day = rep("Mon", n),
                     Time = 1:n,
                     Temper = round(rnorm(n, 4, 2), 0))

# --- convert factor to numeric
mframe <- as.data.frame(sapply(dframe, as.numeric))

# --- function to use on variables 
pfun <- function(x, coef = 1/4){

        # x <- mframe$Time ; coef <- .25 ;
        newp <- x[1:(length(x)-1)] + diff(x, lag = 1) * coef
        res <- c(rbind(x[1:(length(x) -1) ], newp) , x[length(x)] )

        return( res )
}

# --- base R way

# pfun( mframe$Time )
# sapply(mframe, pfun, .5)
apply(mframe, 2, pfun)

dframe_final <- as.data.frame ( apply(mframe, 2, pfun) )
# str(dframe_final)

# --- get Day's or other factors back
for(col in names(dframe)[sapply(dframe, is.factor)]){
        dframe_final[[col]] <- factor(dframe_final[[col]])
        levels( dframe_final[[col]] ) <- levels(dframe[[col]])
}
```

#### dplyr

```r
# --- dplyr way
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lfactors <- dframe %>% 
        map_if(is.factor, levels)

dframe2 <- dframe %>% 
         as_tibble %>%
        map_dfr(as.numeric) %>% 
        map_dfr(pfun) %>% 
        mutate_at(.vars = names(dframe)[sapply(dframe, is.factor)], .funs = factor)

# --- get Day's or other factors back
for(col in names(dframe)[sapply(dframe, is.factor)]){
        dframe2[[col]] <- factor(dframe2[[col]])
        levels( dframe2[[col]] ) <- levels(dframe[[col]])
}
```

#### data.table

```r
# --- data.table way
library(data.table)

dframe3 <- data.table(dframe)

dframe3 <- dframe3[ , lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
dframe3 <- dframe3[ , lapply(.SD, pfun)]

# --- get Day's or other factors back
for(col in names(dframe)[sapply(dframe, is.factor)]){
        dframe3[ , (col) := factor(get(col)) ]
        levels( dframe3[[col]] ) <- levels(dframe[[col]])
}
```